# How to wait for gcsfuse to write-through (flush) to the GCS storage bucket?

Tags: google-cloud-storage, google-compute-engine, gcsfuse

After a Compute Engine worker node writes files into a **gcsfuse** mounted local directory and closes them, I want it to *synchronously flush the data through to GCS* before it notifies other worker nodes that all the files are ready. This is to ensure synchronization between workers.

**Q.** How to ask gcsfuse to write-through to GCS, then wait for that to complete?

Ideas:

- Run the Linux `sync` command?
- Unmount the directory then wait for that `fusermount` command to return? (Besides the write-through time, would it take more than a second or two to unmount then remount for the next worker task?)
- Make all the programs in this task call `fsync()` on all their output files? That'd be challenging.
- Write an additional file, then `flush()` and `fsync()` that one?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have a look at [gcsfuse semantics](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/gcsfuse/blob/master/docs/semantics.md#modifications):

> Inodes may be opened for writing. Modifications are reflected
>   immediately in reads of the same inode by processes local to the
>   machine using the same file system. After a successful fsync or a
>   successful close, the contents of the inode are guaranteed to have
>   been written to the GCS object with the matching name if the object's
>   generation and meta-generation numbers still matched the source
>   generation of the inode. (They may not have if there had been
>   modifications from another actor in the meantime.) There are no
>   guarantees about whether local modifications are reflected in GCS
>   after writing but before syncing or closing.

So if your worker closes the files after writing them subsequent dependencies should see them consistently.